# How to load s3 open dataset in google colaboratory?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am trying to access spacenet challenge dataset(https://registry.opendata.aws/spacenet/) in google colaboratory. How to get it in google colaboratory?

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an AWS account and configure IAM user and generate AccessKey and Secret AccessKey.

With CoLab,

```
s3r = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
buck = s3r.Bucket('bucket name')
buck.download_file(remotefilename,localfilename)
```

Here is the boto3 documentation to start with.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html

One more thing to note. When you download the data **AWS will charge your account** which may come under your free tier.

That is the reason you need to do all these the download bucket is configured as requestor pays.

You can learn about Amazon S3 pricing here,

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

**EDIT1:**

Install aws s3 cli tools from the below link,

https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

and follow the instructions for spacenet data access here,

https://medium.com/the-downlinq/getting-started-with-spacenet-data-827fd2ec9f53

Hope it helps.

Comment: what are bucket name,remotefilename, localfilename? give examples kindly

Comment: Added more info. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I've created my bucket, in s3. What should I do next?

Comment: Added more links, check it out and share how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

## Accessing AWS S3 from Google Colab

You need to have an AWS account, configure IAM, and generate your access key and secret access key to be able to access S3 from Colab. You also need to install the awscli library to your colab environment:

1. Install the awscli library

   `!pip install awscli`
2. Once installed, configure AWS by running aws configure:

   `!aws configure`

   [image: aws configure]

   Enter your access_key and secret_access_key in the text boxes, and press enter.
3. Now you can download any file from S3:

   `!aws s3 cp s3://{bucket_name}/filepath_on_s3 ./{download_location} --recursive`

   You will be notified once the download is complete, and the downloaded file(s) will be available in the location you specified to be used as you wish.

   To upload a file, just reverse the source and destination arguments:

   `!aws s3 cp ./{upload_from} s3://{bucket_name}`

Comment: I tried this but it gave me an import error.  It seems none of the awscli command can be run.
`ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)`